# How to wrapped angularjs promises in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, csom, angularjs

I'm writing an app that requires the use of `$.getScript` quite extensively. I've pushed it into its own function, for ease of use, but now I need to make sure that the function itself is synchronous.

Unfortunately, i am getting error `exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at n.getMyTask`

```
        var getRequest = function (query) {
            var query = query + listEndPoint;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
            function execCrossDomainRequest() {
                var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
                executor.executeAsync({
                    url: appweburl + query + hostweburl + "'",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    },
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
        };
```

---

```
    var getTaskByUser = function (userID) {
        var query = listEndPoint + "GetByTitle('Asana2')/Items?$select=Title,Category,ID,PriorityCod,Desc2,AssignedTo,CONTRACT_HDR_ID,Status&$filter=Status ne 'compleated' and AssignedTo eq '" + userID + "' &$orderby=Id" ;
        return baseSvcOffice.getRequest(query);
    };
```

---

```
    $scope.getMyTask = function getMyTask() {
        taskSvc.getTaskByUser($scope.LoginUser.status)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
        });
    };
```

Comment: is it hosted or provider hosted app?

Comment: it is sharepoint hosted.. and now i am trying this to deploy in office365

Comment: For share sharepoint hosted app, you need not to use SP.RequestExecutor. See my article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002526/SharePoint-and-Angularjs. Also check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getRequest` does not return any promise and that is the reason of your error. Try following code. It may work or not.

```
var getRequest = function (query) {
    var query = query + listEndPoint;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
    function execCrossDomainRequest() {
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: appweburl + query + hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }
        });
    };
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: Which one my answer or article?

Comment: Your answer....